# Registrando nova data no MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Quando eu registro o item pela primeira vez no banco de dados ele pega a data em que foi criada e salva na database, o problema acontece quando eu edito no programa o item e depois salvo na database ele salva uma nova data.

Item:

```
String nome;
int valor;
java.sql.Timestamp datacriado;

public Item(String nome, int valor, java.sql.Timestamp datacriado){
    this.nome = nome;
    this.valor = valor;
    this.datacriado = datacriado;
}
get e set;
```

Criando novo item:

```
 public void CriarItem(String nome, int valor){
 java.sql.Timestamp data = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());

 Item novoitem = new Item(nome, valor, data);
 registrarItem(novoitem);
 }
```

registrarItem no banco de dados:

```
    String qy;
public void registrarItem(Item novoitem){
 qy = "INSERT INTO Itens (Nome, Valor, DataCriado) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = MySQL.getConn().prepareStatement(qy);
        ps.setString(1, novoitem.getNome());
        ps.setInt(2, novoitem.getValor());
        ps.setTimeStamp(3, novoitem.getDataCriado());
        ps.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

E por último quando edito e salvo (onde eu acho que é o problema):

```
public void salvarItem(Item novoitem){
        qy = "UPDATE Itens SET Nome=?, Valor=? WHERE Nome=?";
        if (novoitem != null) {
            try {
                PreparedStatement ps = MySQL.getConn().prepareStatement(qy);
                ps.setString(1, novoitem.getNome());
                ps.setInt(2, novoitem.getValor());
                ps.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Mas se eu coloco no salvarItem para escrever no console a data do item, aparece a data de criação correta, mas depois do executeUpdate(); ele escreve uma nova data no banco de dados (Só acontece quando eu edito)

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi, tive que mudar a coluna DataCriado para o formato datetime em vez de timestamp porque o timestamp estava configurado para atualizar sozinho.